# Reuse cached selector inside a child selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var $container = $('div#myContainer');
var $panels = $('div#myContainer > div');
```

Is it possible to reuse the selector I've already cached in $container within the next child selector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
var $container = $('div#myContainer');
var $panels = $container.children('div');
```

This selects **only** the children like you have currently, using it as the context argument actually calls `.find()` internally, finding all descendants instead of only direct children.

Comment: @Crescent - True, but it's far less efficient, getting child nodes and checking them against a selector is a much faster operation than a `.find()` :)

Comment: Just making sure readers understand that `find` does not mean recursive descent, it can work on direct children too. The way your answer reads (to me) places that into doubt :)

Comment: @Crescent - It does find all descendants as the answer says **then** filters for only direct children.  So yes, it definitely can work, but it's less efficient because it takes a much longer/broader/kinda round-about way to get the set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```
var $container = $('div#myContainer');
var $panels = $('div', $container);
```

This makes use of the additional `context` argument with the standard jQuery() function. You can read up on it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

You could also do this.

```
var $container = $('div#myContainer');
var $panels = $container.find('div');
```

Comment: This doesn't use the "parent > child" selector though, correct? In a quick firebug test it seems to be selecting way too many elements.

Comment: Good call. As always, Nick Craver's answer is better than mine. ;(

Comment: I believe your first example works with var $panels = $(' > div', $container);